# Is it recommend to create sitemaps with query strings (i.e. URL parameters)?

Tags: google, html, sitemap, query-string

I am considering creating a "My products" page on a site where a user will be able to search for product information. This page will also display the product information.

I need google to know about my products, but since these will be on one page, I am considering creating a `sitemap.xml` with query strings, something containing all the links with the URL parameters:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/myproducts.html?productid=1
http://www.mywebsite.com/myproducts.html?productid=2
http://www.mywebsite.com/myproducts.html?productid=3
...
```

Is this a recommended practice? Or is it considered harmful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would this be considered harmful? They're perfectly valid URLs that lead to perfectly valid pages. As long as they are available to humans and search engines alike this is fine.